# Adding legend to layer qplot with two data in single histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to add these two sample into one histogram with one layer for a and another layer for b. After the graph, how do I add legend to the graph?

```
    a <- rnorm(50,10,1)
    b <- rnorm(100,10,2)
    qplot(a,binwidth = 0.5,fill = "Red")+geom_histogram(b,fill="Blue",alpha = 0.2)
```

It gave the following message: Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`

Thank you

Comment: Use a data.frame in long format.

Comment: @Pascal could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
a <- rnorm(50,10,1)
b <- rnorm(100,10,2)
```

you could do

```
qplot(a,binwidth = 0.5,fill = "Red") + 
  geom_histogram(aes(b), as.data.frame(b), fill="Blue",alpha = 0.2)
```

or

```
df <- stack(list(a=a, b=b))
ggplot(df, aes(x=values, fill=ind)) + geom_histogram(alpha=.5, binwidth = 0.5)
```

(The latter one is called [long-format](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) as @Pascal noted.)